# Haskell 'timeout' function doesn't work when applies to 'connect'

Tags: sockets, networking, haskell, tcp

My code is something like this:

```
connectFarEnc ip port = withSocketsDo $ do
  addrinfo <- getAddrInfo (Just (defaultHints {addrFlags = [AI_PASSIVE]})) ip (Just port)
  let addr = head addrinfo          
  sock <- socket (addrFamily addr) Stream defaultProtocol 
  connected <- timeout 2000000 $ connect sock (addrAddress addr)
  print $ show connected
  return (sock, connected)
```

I expect timeout of two second if cannot connect to the server, but it doesn't work. Instead, throw out an exception of connection failed, and quit the program.

How should I deal with this situation to avoid quit?

Comment: Where is the code for `timeout` coming from?  Have you tried to catch the exception? We need more input.

Comment: Hi, timeout is imported from System.Timeout. I just tried 'catch' and it can avoid quit, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You got a definite answer from the server, which produced a 'connection refused'. The timeout is for when you get no answer at all.

Comment: No. The scenario i described is with no server running.

Comment: Yes. That produces a definite answer from the server host, specifically an RST segment, which becomes 'connection refused', as I said. You only get no response if packets are lost, or dropped by firewalls, or on some platforms when the listen backlog queue is full.